# conditionals inside Promise.join()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bluebird, es6-promise

I have trouble to get a bluebird Promise flow right, suppose all the queries return Promise, what's the best way to handle the following logic:

```
Promise.join(query1(), query2(), (result1, result2) => {
 if (result1 === "Something") {
   query3()
 } else {
    // do nothing
 }
})
```

How can I continue to process the return value of the join method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue the flow, you need to return something from the handlers. In your case, you need to return the value returned by `query3`, like this

```
Promise.join(query1(), query2(), (result1, result2) => {
 if (result1 === "Something") {
   return query3();
 }
});
```

Now that `query3()` returns a Promise, you can attach a then handler to the `join`'s result and get the value resolved by `query3`, like this

```
Promise.join(query1(), query2(), (result1, result2) => {
 if (result1 === "Something") {
   return query3();
 }
})
.then((value_resolved_from_query3) => {
    // do something with value_resolved_from_query3
});
```

Comment: what if  it goes to the else branch? would then() still be called?

Comment: @Sawyer It will still be called, but as we don't return anything explicitly, `undefined` will be passed to `value_resolved_from_query3`

Comment: How can I attach a catch all error handler to this expression?

Comment: @Sawyer Just like attaching a `then` handler, attach a `.catch` handler.